# understanding a proof which uses induction on the length of a formula

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic

This comes from Shoenfield's textbook Mathematical Logic. Here is the theorem and its proof:

> **If $u_1,\dots,u_n, u_1',\dots,u_n'$ are designators and $u_1\dots u_n$
>   and $u_1'\dots u_n'$ are compatible,  then $u_i$ is $u_i'$ for
>   $i=1,2,\dots,n$.**
>
> **Proof:** We use induction on the length of $u_1\dots u_n$. We write
>   $u_1$ as $vv_1\dots v_k$. $u_1'$ begins with $v$ and has the form
>   $vv_1'\dots v_k'$. $u_1$ is compatible with $u_1'$, so $v_1\dots v_k$
>   is compatible with $v_1'\dots v_k'$. By induction hypothesis, $v_i$ is
>   $v_i'$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k$. So $u_1$ is $u_1'$. From this it follows
>   that $u_2\dots u_n$ is compatible with $u_2'\dots u_n'$; so by the
>   induction hypothesis, $u_i$ is $u_i'$ for $i=2,\dots,n$.

I include his definitions below. I have trouble understanding this proof because

1) I'm not sure what the inductive hypothesis is (can somebody make it explicit and how it's being applied?) and

2) I'm not sure what is meant by "induction on the length of $u_1\dots u_n$". He makes me think that the induction hypothesis is a statement along the lines of "something is true for all symbols up to a certain positive integer $m$". But in the proof we only speak of the designators... which are recursive and we don't refer to the symbols which make up $v_1,\dots,v_k$.

I would just appreciate it if somebody can expand (make explicit) this proof since I don't see its structure. This is the first proof of the textbook, lol.

DEFINITIONS AND CONVENTIONS:

The symbol of the first-order language are $\neg,\lor,\exists$, symbols for variables, and symbols for functions and predicates.
Shoenfield reserves the following letters (and their subscripted and "primed" counterparts) as syntactic variables.
$u, v$ are variables for expressions, $f$ is a variable for functions, $p$ is a variable for predicates, $a$ is a variable for terms, $x$ is a variable for variables of the language.

He defines the terms of the first-order language as being 1) variables, or 2) $fa_1a_2\dots a_n$ where $f$ is an $n$-ary function and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are terms ($n$ can be 0, and when it is, this is a constant). He defines the formulas as 1) $pa_1\dots a_n$ where $p$ is an $n$-ary predicate and $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are terms, 2) $\neg u$ where $u$ is a formula, 3) $\lor uv$ where $u,v$ are formulas, or 4) $\exists xu$ where $u$ is a formula.

He defines two expressions as being compatible if you can obtain one by adding an expression to the right of the other (one is a substring of the other). He defines a designator as being a term or a formula (since all terms and formulas in this language have the generic form $uv_1\dots v_n$ where $u$ is a symbol and $v_1, \dots, v_n$ are designators and $n$ can be 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the theorem as being rewritten as follows:

If $m$ is a natural number, $u_1,\dots,u_n, u_1',\dots,u_n'$ are designators, the string $u_1\dots u_n$ has exactly $m$ symbols,  and $u_1\dots u_n$ and $u_1'\dots u_n'$ are compatible, then $u_i$ is $u_i'$ for $i=1, 2,\dots,n$.

The proof is by induction on $m$.

In the proof, the induction hypothesis is: if $u_1,\dots,u_n, u_1',\dots,u_n'$ are designators, the string $u_1\dots u_n$ has fewer than $m$ symbols,  and $u_1\dots u_n$ and $u_1'\dots u_n'$ are compatible, then $u_i$ is $u_i'$ for $i=1, 2,\dots,n$.

Comment: How do we know that $v_1\dots v_k$ has $\leq m$ symbols when he applies the inductive hypothesis the first time? How do we know $u_2\dots u_n$ has $\leq m$ symbols when he applies the hypothesis the second time?

Comment: $v_1\dots v_k$ is shorter than $vv_1\dots v_k$, which is the same as $u_1$.  But the number of symbols in $u_1$ is less than or equal to $m$, the number of symbols in $u_1\dots u_n$. 

Similarly, $u_2\dots u_n$ is shorter than $u_1\dots u_n$, which has length $m$. 

In both cases, the string is shorter because you're omitting one or more symbols at the beginning.

Comment: Oh. $m$ is both a variable that we're inducting on (as part of the hypothesis) and also an upper bound on the length of $u_1\dots u_n$. Maybe that's what I thought was confusing.

Comment: Is $m$ an upper bound of the length, or exactly equal to the length of $u_1\dots u_n$? If the latter, then you should change your post.

Comment: You're right. I wrote my previous comment too quickly; $m$ is an upper bound on the length of $u_1\dots u_n$.  So that comment should read:

... But the number of symbols in $u_1$ is less than or equal to the number of symbols in $u_1\dots u_n$, which is less than or equal to $m$.  Similary, $u_2\dots u_n$ is shorter than $u_1\dots u_n$, which has length less than or equal to $m$....

Comment: I've changed the restated theorem in my answer so that $m$ is equal to the number of symbols in $u_1\dots u_n$.  Either way works, but this way is probably clearer.

Comment: Ok, another thing: when using finite strong induction, I thought the form was "assume $P(x)$ is true for $x<k$ (for some $k=0,1,\dots,m$), prove $P(k)$"? Isn't that how you adapt strong induction to the finite case? If not, why not? In this proof, it seems we assume $P(x)$ for every $x<m$ and then prove $P(m)$, which is something different.

Comment: For strong induction on $m$, the induction hypothesis is "For all $x < m$, $P(x)$", and you want to prove $P(m)$.

By the way, I think this proof is clearest with strong induction, but if you prefer to avoid strong induction, go back to the original restatement of the theorem, with "at most $m$ symbols" instead of "exactly $m$ symbols".

Comment: When you say $u_1\dots u_n$ has at most $m$ symbols, you're basically using $m$ as I was using $k$ in my form of strong induction, correct?

Comment: Yes, I phrased it using $m$ to match my restatement of the theorem in the answer.  (I'm avoiding using the letter $k$ because Shoenfield uses $k$ in his proof to mean something else.)  The point is that the induction hypothesis for strong induction reads "for **all** natural numbers $x < m$, ...", not "for **some** natural number $x < m$, ...."

Comment: wait, i'm still confused about the form. In strong induction we want $P(0),P(1),\dots, P(j-1)$ to imply $P(j)$ (and $j$ varies). If we want to prove something about all naturals, then $j$ takes on every positive integer. The form you're giving me still makes me think that all we're proving is $P(0),P(1),\dots, P(m-1)$ implies $P(m)$ where $m$ is fixed (but if this is the form of the argument, how do we know $P(0),P(1)\dots, P(m-1)$ hold?). $m$ is an upper bound, but we need something to vary across all expressions of length $\leq$ the length of $u_1\dots u_n$.

Comment: we're given the expression $u_1\dots u_n$ and you've declared $m$ to be an upper bound on the length of $u_1\dots u_n$, so $m$ is some fixed positive integer.

Comment: and i guess i don't understand your original decision of making it an upper bound on the length as opposed to just being the length. i'm not trying anything fancy, i do want the proof to be done by strong induction.

Comment: $m$ is not declared to be the length of $u_1\dots u_n$.  It's the other way around -- $m$ comes first, and we're looking at any  $u_1\dots u_n$ that happens to have $m$ symbols.  The theorem is $(\forall m) P(m)$, where $P(m)$ is of the form "for all designators $u_1, \dots , u_n, u_1', ..., u_n'$, if the string $u_1\dots u_n$ has exactly $m$ symbols, then ...."

Comment: It's of no importance whether the theorem is stated as "...$u_1\dots u_n$ has exactly $m$ symbols..." or "...$u_1\dots u_n$ has $m$ or fewer symbols...". The first formulation would require strong induction to prove, and the second would use regular induction, but the argument is essentially the same either way. Once you're comfortable with such things, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: This is my version of another small lemma in the book (using induction): https://www.dropbox.com/s/2johchgi94fmo0n/desig.pdf?dl=0. Does it make sense to you? If I could upvote your comments, I would.

Comment: It's all OK, except for the way it starts.  It doesn't really mean anything to say, "Let $m = 0, 1, 2, \dots$"  You could take out the first sentence and replace the second sentence with "The proof is by induction on the length of $u$."

Comment: Well I guess I was just trying to say "let $m$ be a natural number". Anyway, thank you.